# how to split string into words?

Tags: regex, tcl, expect

contents of **vlan_outcome**

```
show int description | include Vl[0-9]+
Vl1                            admin down     down
Vl150                          up             up
```

how can i put the follwing regex into variables?

```
var1 = Vl1  var2 = admin down var3 = down
war2 = Vl150 war3 = up        war3 = up
```

**to be more correct i want the assignment to happen(var1 = Vl1 or war1 = Vl150) only when their status shows up for both columns**

so far i am trying and trying with failure :

```
foreach element [ split $vlan_outcome "\n" ] {
#regexp (Vl\[0-9\]+)(\[\[:blank:\]\]+)(.*)(\[\[:blank:\]\]+)(.*) ignore vlan state1 state2
puts $element
}
```

Comment: I see you have 'admin down'. Does that mean that you also have 'admin up' and would those qualify to be assigned a variable?

Comment: Depending on your exact case, maybe `switch -regexp -matchvar` could be useful too. See the example at https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/switch.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question should be how to [Splitting a String Into Words](http://wiki.tcl.tk/989#pagetoc37df483c).

So if you loop the data line by line, just split the line into words with regex as followings:

```
set data [regexp -inline -all -- {\S+} $line]
if {[lindex $data 1] == "up" && [lindex $data 2] == "up"} {
    set value [lindex $data 0]
}
```

Comment: S+ repersents spaces, -inline reperesents that regexp will working on single line and all represent that regex performs the operation of all occurences of spaces----Am i correct

Comment: `-inline` means **return as a list**. you may want to check [regexp](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/regexp.htm#M13) man page.

Comment: @munish: The regular expression `\S+` (the _capital_ matters) matches sequences of one or more _non_-spaces.